# How to tell vsftpd which ssl to use

Tags: ssl, vsftpd, rhel8

I already have vsftp set up with an SSL which is working fine.  The issue is that the SSL is for the server's host name and not one of my client's.  This client has to be PCI compliant, so when the PCI scan takes place it checks the FTP ports and sees that the SSL is not associated with my client's URL.  My question is how can I set vsftp up to serve an SSL based off the IP address or the hostname?

vsftpd version 3.0.3

Red Hat 8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this on Red Hat's site (https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5172631).

Essentially, the default configuration file is located at `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`.  You need to update this file to listen to the default IP address for the server using `listen_address=...`.  Then, copy that file to `/etc/vsftpd/[site].conf` and change the listen_address to the one for the other site.  (Obviously, you have to have different IP addresses for different sites for this to work.)

Once done, enable vsftpd.target and start it:

```
systemctl enable vsftpd.target
systemctl start vsftpd.target
```

I also had to restart vsftpd to get this to work:

```
systemctl restart vsftpd
```

After that, when connecting to FTP for site 1, everything worked as expected.  When connecting to site 2 (the one with it's own unique SSL) I got the correct SSL.